# Select date greater with LIKE condition

Tags: mysql

I have tried but can't imagine how I can select, with a LIKE and a GREATER condition:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date > '2011-12-31' AND date LIKE "%-12-31"
```

So, if a user send `date` as the follow: `1950-12-31`, I need to get all date GREATER than date posted and which MONTH and DAY is LIKE `%-12-31`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `LIKE`. Try this

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE
    date > '2011-12-31'
    AND MONTH(date) = 12
    AND DAY(date) = 31
```

I don't have MySQL to test but you get the idea I hope.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select * from table1 where date> urdate
And extract(month from date) = extract (month from Urdate)
And extract(day from date) = extract (day from urdate)
;
```

Comment: @Gabriel in my code you don't have to specify month and day though ;-)  check it out if you like....

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend any solution which requires a function on the left side of an equality considering that these solutions would require a full table scan; a no-no on large tables.

I would recommend that both dates ranges be determined before the query is constructed and then simply use a BETWEEN. Also add an index on the date column.

```
select * from table1 where date between :1 and :2
```

Where :1 and :2 are parameters.

HTH